# Bootstrap Carousel Fit Slide to Screen - Not Responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am trying to make my carousel responsive to resizing, and mobile devices. However, when I resize the screen, the actual images do not stay within the card that I have the carousel in.

The website is actually live, so if you wanted to take a look, please visit wwww.alysaandjordanplustwo.baby

Excuse my skills - I am learning front-end for the first time.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Alysa and Jordan Plus Two | Home </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body style="background-image: url(img/background.png); background-size:cover;">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark" style="background-color: #6C3400;" >
            <a class="navbar-brand" style="color: white;" href="#">Jordan and Alysa Plus Two</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="background-color: #6C3400;">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active" >
                  <a class="nav-link" style="color: #FFCD73;" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" style="color: white;" href="photo_gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" style="color: white;" href="registry.html">Registry</a>
                </li>
                
                <div class="dropdown nav-link" style="padding: none; margin: none;">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="about.html" style="background-color: #6c3400; color: white;" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      About Us
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                      <a class="dropdown-item no-border" href="baby_b_memorial.html">Baby B Memorial</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
                
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="color: white;" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>

          <div class="container justify-content-center">

            <div class="row justify-content-center"> 


              <div class="card justify-content-center" style="margin-top: 1rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width: 800px; height: 400px" >
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner justify-content-center">
                      <div class="carousel-item justify-content-center active " style="width:800px; height:400px;">
                        <img class="card-img"  src="img/first_halloween_resized.jpg"  alt="First slide">
                      </div>
                      <div class="carousel-item justify-content-center" style="width:800px; height:400px;" >
                        <img class="card-img"  src="img/2nd_image_resized.jpeg" alt="Second slide">
                      </div>
                      <div class="carousel-item justify-content-center" style="width:800px; height:400px;">
                        <img class="card-img" src="img/third_slide.svg" alt="Third slide">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          </div>

            <div class="container text-center" style="background-color: #FFCD73; border-radius: 10px; height: 100%; width: 100%; margin-top: 5vh;">
                <h3 style="font-style:italic; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px;">"Don't find love. Let love find you. <br> That is why it is called falling in love because you do not force yourself to fall,<br> you just fall" <br> - Author Unknown</h3>
                <h2 style="font-style:italic; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px;">~~~</h2>
                <a href="gender_reveal.html" style="font-style:bold; color: #6c3400; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px;"><h3 style="font-style:bold; color: #6c3400; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px;">Find out our babies gender!</h3></a>
            </div>
        

          <div class="container" style="padding-top: 5vh;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg">
                    <!-- Photo on the left --> 
                    <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block img-thumbnail" src="img/first_photo.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 5vh;">
                </div>
            <div class="col-sm" style="background-color: #FFCD73; border-radius: 10px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 10vh;">
                <H2>Our Story</H2>
                <p>Alysa and I met for the first time at Kennesaw State University in the Fall 2022 semester. I was the first one to message Alysa, as we were in a student group where we could all talk about our majors and meet new people. I decided to message Alysa to see if she wanted to meet and perhaps study together. Which is just what we did – we ended up studying together, and I offered as much help as I could remember while she was taking Calculus. It had been years since I took Calculus 1, and I was very rusty. Before we knew it, we were always around each other, almost every possible minute that we could. Eventually, I believe, we ended up falling for each other, even though we both were hesitant to enter a relationship. I am so, so, so glad that we met, and for the next steps of our life together!  <br><br> - Jordan | September 7th, 2022 </p>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         
   
    <!-- Footer -->
<footer class="page-footer font-small white pt-4" style="background-color: #6C3400; margin-top: 10vh;">

    <!-- Footer Links -->
    <div class="container-fluid text-center text-md-left">
  
      <!-- Grid row -->
      <div class="row">
  
        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-md-0 mt-3">
  
          <!-- Content -->
          <h5 style="color: #FFFFFF;">Thank you for visiting our website!</h5>
          <p style="color: #FFFFFF;">Please be respectful, and only share this website with immediate family for the time being. Thank you! <br><br>- Jordan & Alysa</p>
  
        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->
  
        <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none pb-3">
  
        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">
  
          <!-- Links -->
          <h5 class="text-uppercase" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Registry Links</h5>
  
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
              <a href="https://www.amazon.com/baby-reg/J48Z6DSREQX9">Amazon</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Buy Buy Baby</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Target</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
  
        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->
  
        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">
  
          <!-- Links -->
          <h5 class="text-uppercase" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Quick Links</h5>
  
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">RSVP Form (Coming Soon)</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
  
        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->
  
      </div>
      <!-- Grid row -->
  
    </div>
    <!-- Footer Links -->
  
    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3" style="color:#FFFFFF">Copyright &copy; 2022:
      <a href="https://jordanviehmeyer.dev"> Written with &heartsuit; by Jordan Viehmeyer (Dad)</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->
  
  </footer>
  <!-- Footer -->

  <!-- Javascript-->
   <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 

</body>
</html>
```

I have not modified the CSS code of the carousel itself, so it is bootstrap standard using the min.css file.

The photos are sized 800 width, 400 height. That is how I'd like them to display, but proportionally.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all `style="width:800px; height:400px;"` from your code. By adding this you forcing the element to a fixed size, so element wont be responsive.

In your carousel replace `.card-img` class with `d-block w-100` classes, as per this example... (don't use card-img class)

Follow these bs docs... [Carousel with indicators](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/carousel/#with-indicators)

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```